# an optimization question

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, maxima-minima, discrete-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Consider a consumer who is trying to maximize:

max $\sum_{t=1}^{M}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{t} (x_{t})^{1/2}$

s.t. $\sum_{t=1}^{M} x_{t} \leq 1$

($\forall x_{t} \geq 0, t=1, \ldots, M$ $(t < \infty)$)

I do not know how to incorporate $x_{t} \leq 1 $  and $x_{t} \geq 0 $ as constraints. Any ideas?

The objective function can be rewritten:

max $(\frac{1}{2})(x_1)^{1/2}+(\frac{1}{2})^2(x_2)^{1/2}+(\frac{1}{2})^3(x_3)^{1/2}...$

but I am still confused as to how to set up the lagrangian.

Thanks!

Comment: Once you do the sum in the second equation you automatically have $x_t \le 1$ if you can do $x_t \ge 0$.  Since you don't tell us what equations and inequalities you can write, we can't help.  I would just write $x_t \ge 0$ for all $t$ and be done.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, I have just fixed it. It is for all non-negative t, where t is finite.

Comment: Then you already have $x_t \ge 0$.  The sum enforces $x_t \le 1$ so you don't need to incorporate it.

Comment: Right, I see! I did not notice that. Does this mean that this is basically an unconstrained optimization problem?

Comment: You still have the constraint that all the $x_t$ are nonnegative.  I don't know if your terminology allows that and still calls it unconstrained.  Without that constraint I could make $x_1$ huge and positive and $x_2$ huge and negative and have the objective function huge squared.

Comment: Thank you, I think understand now. I am wondering now how to go about setting up the lagrangian with these equality constraints.

Comment: If we view the expression you want to maximize as a function $f(x_1,...x_M)$, we can see that all the components of its gradient are positive.

Answer (score 0):

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $\sum_{t=1}^M (\sqrt{x_t})^2\sum_{t=1}^M (\dfrac1{2^t})^2\ge \sum_{t=1}^M (\dfrac12)^t(x_t)^{1/2}$

$\sum_{t=1}^M (\dfrac1{2^t})^2=\sum_{t=1}^M (\dfrac1{4^t})=\dfrac{1-(1/4)^M}{1-1/4}=\dfrac{4-(1/4)^{M-1}}{3}$

Thus $\sum_{t=1}^M (\dfrac12)^t(x_t)^{1/2}\le\sum_{t=1}^M (\sqrt{x_t})^2\dfrac{4-(1/4)^{M-1}}{3}=\sum_{t=1}^M (x_t)\dfrac{4-(1/4)^{M-1}}{3}\le \dfrac{4-(1/4)^{M-1}}{3}$

Assuming M is a given fixed integer, the desired maximum would be $\dfrac{4-(1/4)^{M-1}}{3}$.